# How to inject same Dagger 2 dependency with different implementations based on the Context?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have a Dagger 2 dependency that is provided differently if it’s an `Activity` or some other context instance (e.g., a `Service`). Both would refer to the same interface but their implementation varies. How could I organise this using Dagger 2?

Right now, I’m trying with two different components, `ActivityComponent` and `ContextComponent` with their respective modules as follows:

```
@ActivityScope        
@Subcomponent(            
  modules = {                
    ActivityModule.class,                
    ContextModule.class
  })        
public interface ActivityComponent {
}

@Module    
public class ActivityModule {

    @Provides
    @MyActivityQualifier
    public MyObject provideMyObject() {
    }
}


@ContextScope
@Subcomponent(        
  modules = {
    ContextModule.class
  })    
public interface ContextComponent {    }

@Module
public class ContextModule.class {

    @Provides
    public MyObject provideMyObject() {
    }
}
```

Then, if I’m using `MyObject` in an `Activity`, I have to add the qualifier as follows:

```
@Inject @MyActivityQualifier MyObject myObject;
```

This feels wrong but I’m not sure why. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You are using subcomponents.
The question is: Can or should both objects be "visible" (usable, injectable, ...) at the same time?

- **Yes:** You *will* have to use some sort of qualifier. Or else you can't distinguish them.
- **No:** You can "hide" them by not exposing the dependency from the dependent component. You would have to use a normal component instead of `@Subcomponent` in this case, and just don't add the `getMyInterface()` method to your parent component.

And there aren't any other options, because you have 2 components dependent on each other. So your approach looks fine with the information you provide.

*Note* you can also just qualify **one** of your implementations. In my project, I use a qualified `@Named("public")` annotation for a common implementation without user data. If I don't add any qualifier I will just get the other one (unqualified).

---

With *independent* components, e.g. `ActivityAComponent` and `ActivityBComponent` you could just switch which implementation gets provided using different modules.